Read-only mode - misleading?
What does this mean for SE? It has been up on Chemistry StackExchange for the last couple of hours but I still see edits being made to live posts within the last 30 minutes.

Probably the same as this Clear cookies for the site and see if that fixes it

It appears to be a recurring issue. >>Snap<< greg. Could always try a different browser.

Closing this to try and keep things in (mostly) one place. The linked question should explain that clearing cookies should fix this. If that's not the case, please do edit your question to explain that, as it's a different problem, and I'll happily reopen this.
